# Can we collapse image like toolbar text in android..?

Tags: android, imageview, android-toolbar

Is there any way to collapse image view just like we collapsing the toolbar text when we slide up the header, this can be done by using material design.But I need to collapse imageview instead of text.

[image]

Here is the images that we can easily do with the material design.
[Collapsing_toolbar_text_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvbDo.png)

[collapsed_toolbar_text_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZelGk.png)

Below is what I required..[image: observe top selfhelp image @header]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can view this example set by excellent developer!

https://github.com/saulmm/CoordinatorLayoutExample or [this](http://blog.grafixartist.com/toolbar-animation-with-android-design-support-library/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this wonderful library : CollapsingTitleLayout written by Chris Banes in Android team:https://plus.google.com/+ChrisBanes/posts/J9Fwbc15BHN

Code: https://gist.github.com/chrisbanes/91ac8a20acfbdc410a68

Comment: this is not what i required..I want to collapse Image which is there on top ,not the background image.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you place inside Collapsing toolbar gets collapsed nothing required to be done.